# devtools: no browser pages found at WDIO REPL Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, webdriver-io, read-eval-print-loop, wdio

After starting  `wdio repl chrome`, getting following endless looping with no browser pages found, retrying... and The chrome tab is open but not operational, it means you can not call a url etc. Calling devtool is not possible. Chrome version 95.

Actually there is/are no big chance/s at last days. No browser update, maybe the windows has been automatically updated through company daily/weekly Routine.

```
$ wdio repl chrome

2021-12-10T11:09:00.101Z INFO devtools:puppeteer: Initiate new session using the DevTools protocol
2021-12-10T11:09:00.102Z INFO devtools: Launch Google Chrome with flags: --enable-automation --disable-popup-blocking --disable-extensions --disable-background-networking --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-sync --metrics-recording-only --disable-default-apps --mute-audio --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --disable-hang-monitor --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-breakpad --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-renderer-backgrounding --force-fieldtrials=*BackgroundTracing/default/ --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-features=site-per-process,TranslateUI,BlinkGenPropertyTrees --window-position=0,0 --window-size=1200,900
2021-12-10T11:09:01.206Z INFO devtools: Connect Puppeteer with browser on port 59545
2021-12-10T11:09:02.240Z INFO devtools: no browser pages found, retrying...
2021-12-10T11:09:02.342Z INFO devtools: no browser pages found, retrying...
2021-12-10T11:09:02.442Z INFO devtools: no browser pages found, retrying...
2021-12-10T11:09:02.544Z INFO devtools: no browser pages found, retrying...
```

my package.json has following configuration

```
{
  "name": "webdriverio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "wdio:local": "cross-env DEBUG=\"*\" wdio run wdio.local.conf.ts",
    "wdio:ci": "wdio run wdio.ci.conf.ts",
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/chai-as-promised": "^7.1.3",
    "@wdio/cli": "^7.6.0",
    "@wdio/repl": "^7.16.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.24.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.7",
    "debug": "^2.6.9",
    "log4js": "^6.3.0",
    "oracledb": "^5.2.0",
    "pdfkit": "^0.12.3",
    "string-similarity": "^4.0.4",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/debug": "^4.1.7",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.7",
    "@types/oracledb": "^5.2.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.6.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.6.1",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^7.6.0",
    "@wdio/devtools-service": "^7.16.10",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.6.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "chromedriver": "^95.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^7.13.0",
    "fs-extra": "^10.0.0",
    "multiple-cucumber-html-reporter": "^1.18.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.0.0",
    "wdio-cucumberjs-json-reporter": "^1.0.0",
    "wdio-wait-for": "^2.0.3"
  }
}

The @wdio/repl is updated but there is no improvement at the moment.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what it caused but after a fresh new start of window 10 solved `wdio repl chrome`  problem.